# External JavaScript files in Umbraco are not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, file, reference, external, umbraco

I have made an Umbraco 4.9 application and it works fine in all browsers except in Internet Explorer. The external JavaScript files are not working or loaded in IE. The references in the head section are here:

```
<head>
      <title><umbraco:Item field="seo_titel" recursive="true" runat="server" /></title>
      <meta name="description" content="<umbraco:Item field="seo_beskrivelse" recursive="true" runat="server" />" />
      <meta name="keywords" content="<umbraco:Item field="seo_keywords" runat="server" />" />

      <link href="/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="/css/top_menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="/css/generelt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

      <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/pnd4dbj.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

      <script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>          
      <script src="/scripts/basic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/screen_size_main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="ContentPlaceholderHead" runat="server">
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </head>
```

I have tried to run the appication local and from a webserver and it still does not work in IE.

Comment: Does it throw an Exception?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: if your having trouble with typeKit have you added the domain in kit settings to the kit editor you are using?